# Conversion from double to time

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

The application I'm developing does distance calculations with type double. Thus, at the end I have a variable type double (say `deferTime = 0.024 seconds`), which is a ratio based on the distance between two nodes.

I want to use this ratio to schedule an event which is type `time::seconds`. Below the API definition:

```
scheduleEvent (const time::nanoseconds & after, const EventCallback & callback)
```

In my library file I declared `deferTime` as following:

```
time::seconds meanWaiting;
```

In my .cpp file I'm assigning the ratio to `deferTime`: (** updated using seconds instead of nanoseconds **)

```
meanWaiting = std::chrono::duration<double>{(maxWait * 
              (maxDistance - distance) / maxDistance)};
```

but I get the following error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘boost::chrono::seconds {aka boost::chrono::duration<long int>}’ and ‘std::chrono::duration<double>’)
 meanWaiting = std::chrono::duration<double>{(maxWait * (maxDistance - distance) / maxDistance)};
             ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/chrono/chrono.hpp:11:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/chrono/include.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/chrono.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/local/include/ndn-cxx/util/time.hpp:26,
                 from /usr/local/include/ndn-cxx/name-component.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/local/include/ndn-cxx/name.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/local/include/ndn-cxx/interest.hpp:25,
                 from ./../core/common.hpp:57,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/include/boost/chrono/duration.hpp:465:19: note: candidate: boost::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& boost::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>::operator=(const boost::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>&) [with Rep = long int; Period = boost::ratio<1l>]
     duration& operator=(const duration& rhs) = default;
               ^
/usr/include/boost/chrono/duration.hpp:465:19: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::chrono::duration<double>’ to ‘const boost::chrono::duration<long int>&’
```

The ndn-cxx libraries can be found [here](https://named-data.net/doc/ndn-cxx/current/doxygen/de/daf/time_8cpp.html).

Comment: I hadn't even really noticed before that you were using the non-cxx libraries.  If you're interested, here's a really full featured date/time library built on std::chrono:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: should be Duration not Time. These are different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using namespace std::chrono;
meanWaiting = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(
              duration<double>{(maxWait * (maxDistance - distance) / maxDistance)});
```

The `duration<double>` turns your double, into `seconds` stored as a double.  Next you cast those `seconds` to `nanoseconds`.

In C++17 you'll be able to replace `duration_cast` with another rounding mode if you want:

- `duration_cast`: truncate towards zero.
- `floor`: truncate towards negative infinity.
- `ceil`: truncate towards positive infinity.
- `round`: rounds towards nearest integral, to even on tie.

If it is important for your application, and you can't wait until C++17, open-source implementations of these are floating around and easy to find.

In general, there are two cases when you need to use `duration_cast`, or some other explicit rounding mode:

1. When you assign or copy from a fine duration to a coarse duration (e.g. `nanoseconds` to `seconds`), and
2. When you assign or copy from a floating-point-based duration to an integral-based duration.

Both of the above conversions involve truncation error.  And so `<chrono>` requires you to explicitly acknowledge that you want the truncation by using `duration_cast`.

For conversions that don't involve truncation error (e.g. integral seconds to integral nanoseconds, or integral duration to *any* floating point duration), you can use implicit conversion syntax.

In the modified answer where `meanWaiting` is `seconds` instead of `nanoseconds`, the `duration_cast` is still required because you will be truncating the fractional part of the double-based `duration`:

```
meanWaiting = duration_cast<seconds>(
              duration<double>{(maxWait * (maxDistance - distance) / maxDistance)});
```

For a complete video tutorial on `<chrono>` please see my Cppcon 2016 talk:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Comment: Thank you! I still got an error however. I updated the question to reflect the new error and I also tried to simplify it using seconds instead of nanoseconds

Comment: Updated answer.